# Setting java buffer to read from write position - offset

Tags: java, circular-buffer

I have created a circular byte buffer in java based on a few existing resources and tutorials. I am using java sound's linear buffer, and writing into a large 5 second circular buffer.

For one of my functions, I would like to read from the circular buffer a few ms before the current write position, not from the start point of the circular buffer.  How do I achieve this?

Currently I read from buffer using:

```
double[] readFromBuffer = new double[halfWindowSize];
input.circ.read(readFromBuffer, 0, halfWindowSize, true);
```

I understand that where the 0 is, is the offset, but not sure how this is used. It appears I want to query the current write position of the buffer, and then update the read position with a negative offset of x bytes (however many equates to a few ms). This needs to be done outside of my loop, as I then continue reading from the buffer in a loop.

Currently when I start reading this starts at the beginning of the buffer, which when graphing can result in up to 5 second delay on input too output, which is too great and makes the software appear laggy.

Any help would be appreciated,  thanks.